# Наложение цвета на изображение

Tags: java, изображения, bufferedimage

Привет всем, в матане не силён нужна помощь.

Есть картинка с прозрачностью ,например

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что мне нужно сделать что-бы после выполнения я получил что-то вроде этого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понимаю ,что нужно разбить на пиксели и с каждым провести некие действия, а потом собрать обратно ,но как это всё будет в виде кода?

Answer (score 1):

По моему мнению, это легче всего сделать в цветовой модели HSL, т.е. если картинка представлена в RGB, то мы переводим её в HSL, где просто равномерно "размазываем" яркость, от 0 у края до 1 в центре. Ссылка на преобразование:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL

Как, по моему мнению выглядит алгоритм, если допустить что прямое и обратное преобразование вы реализовали, и они называются соотв. RGB_TO_HSL(R,G,B) и 
HSL_TO_RGB(H,S,L), где на вход подается 3 числа, и ф-я возвращает 3 числа соотв. другой цветовой модели:

Начинаем с начала картинки (коорд. 0, 0, и движемся до конца, просто как по массиву). Берем значение текущего пикселя из массива, скармливаем его RGB_TO_HSL, получаем представление в HSL. H и L меняем на желаемые, (задаем желаемый цвет в RGB, скармливаем его RGB_TO_HSL, запоминаем H и S, вставляем эти H,S, на место "старых", не меняя L). Скармливаем получившееся HSL_TO_RGB, устанавливаем новые значения пикселя, пока есть пиксели. Не пробовал, по идее должно работать!

Answer (score 0):

Не нужен здесь никакой матанализ.

PNG-24 поддерживает 256 уровней прозрачности. Выставить нужный уровень можно например в редакторе [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/), а затем элементу с картинкой добавляете нужный цвет `background`